# Scheme sum numbers

Tags: scheme

I'm very new to Scheme, how to make a program that sum all the individual digits from a number ?

example: 758 would return 20, because 7 + 5 + 8 = 20

I'm trying to figure out with remainder, but for some reason isnt working

```
(define (remainder a b)
   (- a (* b (floor (/ a b)))) )

(define (somar num)
   (+ (remainder num 10)
      (floor (remainder (/ num 10) 10))
      (floor (remainder (/ num 100) 10)) ) )
```

Comment: What didn't work with your remainder? What did you expect, and how did the program's behaviour differ from your expectation? It sounds like a straightforward operation.

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far

Comment: (define (remainder a b)
 (- a (* b (floor (/ a b))))
)

(define (somar num)
 (+ (remainder num 10) (floor (remainder (/ num 10) 10)) (floor (remainder (/ num 100) 10)) )
)

Comment: Try starting with a function that creates a list of all the digits in the number. Then `(apply + the-list-of-digits)`.

Comment: If there is only one digit, that is the sum; otherwise, it is the result of adding the last digit to the sum of the other digits.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need to define `remainder`, since that is a standard procedure. Secondly, your solution will only work for numbers with three digits or less. Try to call your procedure recursively instead.